# Finding location entering coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am new to QGIS.

Can I find a location on the map I'm working with by entering its coordinates?

If yes, where do I enter these coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

On the bottom of the application you can set extent or the center of the map.

It looks like this:

l[image]

The first button switches between extent and map center.

Comment: No problem, if you think this answers your question, please check this answer as "answered"  underneath the voting box.